# ComboBox binding between viewmodels

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding

I have a `ViewModel` (SortingChart) inside of another `ViewModel` (Sorting). I want to use a `ComboBox` in Sorting to select an amount that is used in SortingChart. How can I use the Combobox from another `ViewModel`

Code-behind Sorting:

```
public class vmSorting : VMBase
{
    //The ComboBox I want to use in the other vm.
    private ComboBox _SelectTop;
    public ComboBox SelectTop
    {
        get { return _SelectTop; }
        set { _SelectTop = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //The content in which the (SortingChart) is loaded.
    private object _MyContent;
    public object MyContent
    {
        get { return _MyContent; }
        set { _MyContent = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //For the Update button.
    private RelayCommand _cmdUpdate;
    public ICommand Update
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cmdUpdate == null)
                _cmdUpdate = new RelayCommand(param => this.Button_Click_Update(param));
            return _cmdUpdate;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_Update(object sender)
    {
        if (sender as string == "UpdateChart")
            MyContent = new AlarmsTopSortingChart();
    }
}
```

Code-behing SortingChart:

```
public class vmSortingChart : VMBase
{
    //Here I want to use the selecteditem from the combobox in (Sorting)
}
```

Comment: You'll need to communicate between ViewModels.
https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/

Comment: `I have a ViewModel (SortingChart) inside of another ViewModel`, this isn't MVVM, you should be using a mediator of some sorts to communicate with other VM's... See [Josh Smiths](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/) implementation...